# Multiple version of keyBy in lodash? (Group values sharing a key as an array)

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

Is there a simple way to achieve this with lodash?

```
_.something([{a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 3, b: 5}, {a: 10}], 'a')

=> { 3: [ {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 3, b: 5 } ], 10: [{ a: 10 }]}
```

That is, group all the values that share the same key together as an array under that key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy) for grouping by a given key.

> Creates an object composed of keys generated from the results of running each element of `collection` thru `iteratee`. The order of grouped values is determined by the order they occur in `collection`. The corresponding value of each key is an array of elements responsible for generating the key. The `iteratee` is invoked with one argument: *(value)*.

```js
console.log(_.groupBy([{ a: 3, b: 4 }, { a: 3, b: 5 }, { a: 10 }], 'a'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. So hard to search for the function you need in the doco.